# Maximum number of elements (excluding the identity)that one need to compute the order, to determine the isomorphism class of Abelian group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I just finished below to exercises.

> If $G$ is Abelian group of order $9$ then, maximum number of elements
> (excluding the identity)that one need to compute the order, to
> determine the isomorphism class of $G$ is $3$

> If $G$ is Abelian group of order $18$ then, maximum number of elements
> (excluding the identity)that one need to compute the order, to
> determine the isomorphism class of $G$ is $6$

**My Question: Is there is general statement regarding this?**

I mean,

> If $G$ is Abelian group of order $n$ then, what is the maximum number of elements (excluding the identity)that one need to compute the order, to determine the isomorphism class of $G$?

Please help

Comment: It's going to depend on $n$. For example, when $n=15$, the answer is $0$ (there is only one group of order $15$, let alone an abelian group). More generally, if $n$ is squarefree, there is only one abelian group of that order and it is cyclic, so again the answer is $0$. On the other hand, if $n=p^k$, you need $(p-1)^{k-1}+1$ in case you get very unlucky in trying to tell apart $(C_p)^{k}$ and $(C_p)^{k-1}\times C_{p^2}$.

Comment: (note; the final one should be "$(C_p)^{k-2}\times C_{p^2}$", but it's too late to edit the typo.)